# Gallery shortcode numerical sorting

Tags: wp-query, shortcode, gallery, media, sort

When I try to sort a Gallery created through the `[gallery]` shortcode by numerical titles I get them sorted in **alphabetical** order. That means that they are sorted like so:

```
1, 3, 34, 4, 56, 6, etc.
```

rather than so:

```
1, 3, 4, 6, 34, 56, etc.
```

Doing some research I came across **[the section of the codex (in `WP_Query`)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters)** explaining this issue. Apparently, setting the `orderby` parameter to `meta_value_num` would enable numerical sorting.

Since `[gallery]` internally uses `get_posts()` ([`wp-includes/media.php::714`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/media.php#L714)), which in turn uses `WP_Query`, I thought the same rules would apply.

Changing the `order_by` attribute in the shortcode to `meta_value_num` doesn't do the trick. I guess that most likely this is the case because I cannot set up the required `meta_key=keyname`.

But not only can I not specify the meta key, I don't have one, and **I don't need one** because I mean to sort them numerically by title.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: There is not much code to post, besides `[gallery link="file" columns="6" orderby="title"]` which gives the *alphabetical* order and `[gallery link="file" columns="6" orderby="meta_value_num"]` which, as stated, doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you can do this with the gallery shortcode, unfortunately.

The Codex doesn't even list `meta_value_num` as an option (though that doesn't mean it couldn't work.) However, you're correct, you must specify a meta-key to use that ordering scheme with WP_Query.

Comment: I know the codex doesn't, but doing some reasearch in the source code made me think it should be possible (considering that it uses `get_posts()`).